# Eclipse plugin detected but not loaded

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am writing a plugin that uses the `compilationParticipant` extension point of the JDT. The plugin isn't working right now and I try to figure out why.

I have one `CompilationParticipant`:

```
public class CompParticipant extends CompilationParticipant {

    private static CompParticipant instance = null;    
    private CompParticipant() {
        super();
        Activator.log("CompilationParticipant initialized");
    }

   public CompParticipant getSingleton() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new CompParticipant();
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void buildStarting(BuildContext[] files, boolean isBatch) {
        Activator.log("Build Starting");
    }
}
```

And one (not lazy) `Activator`:

```
public class Activator extends Plugin implements BundleActivator {

    private static Activator instance;
    public static String PLUGINID = "myplugin";

    public Activator() {
        super();
        log("Activator");
    }

    public static void log(String msg) {        
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Activator();
        instance.getLog().log(new Status(Status.WARNING, PLUGINID, 1, msg, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception { log("Start"); }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {}

}
```

In my manifest I specify:

```
Bundle-Activator: myplugin.Activator
```

And in my plugin.xml I specify:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant">
  <compilationParticipant class="myplugin.CompParticipant" id="myplugin" createsProblems="true">
  </compilationParticipant>
</extension>
```

I exported the plugin to an archive and put the contents in the `dropins` folder. When I start Eclipse I see in the **Installation Details > Configuration** section `*** Plug-in Registry`:
`myplugin (1.0.0) "My Plugin" [Installed]`

However no log messages are printed to the error log (or in the console). Is my logging incorrect or why does my plugin not get run?

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the question, the following looks inconsistent to me:

- An activator should not be manually instantiated, but the framework should do that for you.
- For instantiation by the framework, the activator needs a *public* no-arg constructor.

  - To support singleton access, an activator typically saves `this` from within the constructor or `start()` method.
- To let class loading trigger bundle activation, the bundle should declare `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy`

When all this is corrected, the builder should be able to instantiate your CompilationParticipant (as read from the extension declaration). This instantiation should then activate your bundle and start the activator.